# How to get "starred mails" from Gmail or other mail services using IMAP_tools in django

Tags: django, imap-tools

I am able to get inbox emails and also able to get emails from specific folder but i am unable to get "**starred**" emails.

I tried below code. and i am expecting emails with "**starred flag**" in response.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, A

# Create your views here.
def temp(request):
    

    #Get date, subject and body len of all emails from INBOX folder
    with MailBox('smtp.gmail.com').login('admin@gmail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
        temp="empty"
        for msg in mailbox.fetch():
            temp = (msg.date, msg.subject, msg.html) 

    return HttpResponse(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/blob/master/examples/search.py

```
mailbox.fetch(AND(flagged=True))
```

(A long time ago in a galaxy far far away) star looked like a flag.